# Active Directory B2C get facebook access token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm comparing the new AD B2C features with the social authentication ability in Azure web service.  Using the AD B2C approach I can't seem to find a way to do access the underlying access token from a social provider like facebook.

E.g. in Azure Web Services social authentication there was an http://example.com/.auth/me endpoint that would provide BACK the token to access the social provider's api.

Is that not available in B2C?  If not that seems like a step backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the answer is no (although I wish there was a way).

See this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/22/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/

> OAuth Tokens: With Easy Auth, the application code has direct access to the provider-specific OAuth tokens. This is useful if you want to make graph API calls on behalf of the logged-in user (for example, calling the Facebook Graph to post a photo to the user’s timeline). B2C, however, does not expose the provider OAuth tokens to your application code.

Comment: thanks for confirming... that was my conclusion as well.

Comment: Hi, has anything moved on from this? I've seen this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code regarding OAuth flow but am having difficulty trying to figure out how to configure it in AD and generally within my web app (seems to be very little code samples on this). Basically I would like to use B2C but also get access to the access_token of the provider being used so I can carry on making the relevant graph calls.

Comment: I don't think anything has moved on this.

Comment: Wow, thats pretty painful! So if I wanted access from a client via signup from facebook and email, would it be best to use the native FB SDK and ADB2C for email signups?